# EmacsForMacOSX build 27.2-2 cannot be opened on mac M1

Tags: osx, emacs27, mac

This question is about Emacs 27.2-2 from https://emacsformacosx.com/ on Mac M1. From the release notes<sup>1</sup> M1 support should be added since 27.2-1. However, on latest stable version I was getting an error "This application will not run on your computer. Sorry!". How could I get it run on Mac M1? What was the condition that could throw this error? Thanks.

<sup>1</sup> Refer to the **2021-03-26** update at https://emacsformacosx.com/about and also https://emacsformacosx.com/download/emacs-builds/Emacs-27.2-2.changes

Comment: It won't open for me either. It tells me "“Emacs.app” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should eject the disk image." :-(

Comment: I finally went back and tried 27.2-1 and found that it was working fine on Mac M1. Maybe you could also try and see if it works?

Comment: I wanted to follow up on OP's question from six months ago. Does Emacs 27.2-2 from https://emacsformacosx.com/ work on Mac M1?

Comment: From a brief test, 27.2-2 seems to work on M1. Maybe this thread should be marked resolved?

Comment: 27.2-1 works, but 27.2-3 gives the same error: "This application will not run on your computer." Regression or something?

Comment: I could not get any of 27.2.{1-3} (or `homebrew/cask/emacs`) to work on mini M1 Big Sur. "This application will not run on your computer" or crashes. Finally I upgraded to Monterey - emacs is that important to me - and was able to install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

This same thing happened to me where using `v27.2-3` on an M1 mac gave me the `This application will not run on your computer.` error; however, when I uninstalled the cask and reinstalled the [normal formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/emacs) which at the time of this writing is `27.2`, it ran correctly for me. Would love to see the Emacs team patch the Cask version to run properly on an M1 Mac.